# How to view all "Connections" being referenced from heroku pg:info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

When I run
`heroku pg:info` or `heroku pg:info -a appname` it returns

```
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 2/20
PG Version:  9.4.4
...
```

and the "Connections" line says 2/20. I expect 1 of those connections is the connection generated when I am running the above query. But I can't figure out what the other connection is. I have google analytics running on my application and live statistics show no users. My pg user query in another terminal window also returns no users are logged in. Connections shows 3 if I run `heroku pg:info` in another terminal while doing a user query (still one connection unaccounted for).

Currently I can only think of the following connection possibilities:

1. Users logged into the web interface for the app (in my case none)
2. Users logged into the app via terminal (per terminal instance...in my case 1 when running `heroku pg:info` (connections should say 1/20 but says 2/20) or 2 if I run that command while another terminal is open running `heroku run rails c`. So when I would expect connections to say 2/20 in this example, it says 3/20.

Either way, there is always 1 more connection than I can account for. When I look through documentation on heroku's website all I was able to find was ways to increase available connections. Not what connections represents.

How do I view all "Connections" being referenced from heroku pg:info?

Comment: Any success checking the connections?

Comment: @Bengala I still haven't figured out how to view all connections being referenced from heroku pg:info. What Simone posted in his first paragraph gives a good link about rails connection pools but that didn't lead me to a solution. What he pointed out in his second paragraph was already accounted for in number 2 of the possibilities I listed in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

[Rails uses a connection pool](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections), therefore the number of connections you see may be related to other non-active users that caused a connection to be opened and it has not been recycled yet by the pool.

Moreover, to connect to PG from the Heroku addon and get the stats you actually open a connection to it. That counts against the total number of opened connection, in addition to the ones opened by web requests from visitors).

Comment: "'non-active users that caused a connection to be opened and it has not been recycled yet by the pool" How do I see what these non-active connections that have not been recycled yet are? For example if I run ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.instance_eval { @size } I can get the pool size setting but not what I am trying to find.